# .desktop file drag n' drop not working after Gnome upgrade

Tags: debian, gnome, nautilus, drag-and-drop

On Debian 9 I was able to drag and drop files onto .desktop files and use %F successful. After upgrading to Debian 10 and Gnome 3.30 this is no longer possible. Is there a solution? Thanks.